# Can I use Liquid in a CSS folder to edit settings for home page sections

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

so I'm trying to get something like this

hero.css.liquid

```
.hero_image {
   background-image: url( {{ section.settings.hero-image-image }} )
}
```

hero.liquid

```
<div class: "hero_image"></div>

{% schema %}
{
    "name": "hero",
    "class": "hero-section",
    "settings": [

        {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "hero-image-image",
            "label": "Hero Image"
        }
],    

"presets": [
        {
            "category": "hero",
            "name":"hero"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

is there a way to make something like this work or should i just create a {% style %} section in my hero.liquid folder and put the css i want to edit in there

Answer (score 1):

The file `hero.css.liquid` has no knowledge of your section settings, so you won't be able to reference the section settings in your CSS file.  The `section` Liquid variable only exists inside the matching section file (and any snippets used within it).

This gives us two main options:

a) Move your style settings to the `config/settings_schema.json` file, as theme settings can be accessed in your `.css.liquid` files;

b) Create a `{% style %}` (or `<style>`) tag inside your section file to put your settings.

*Note: When `{% style %}` was first introduced I had some trouble getting it to work exactly as I expected so went back to using `<style>` tags. I think `{% style %}` works better now, but if you have trouble you may want to try a simple HTML tag instead.*